# vcalendar vs icalendar

Tags: android, calendar

What is the difference between vcalendar and icalendar? Is it only the VERSION difference as  1.0 and 2.0 respectively?

For sending a Meeting Request with iCalendar and vcalendar, I specify the MIME type as text/calendar.

The email sent with iCalendar appears as a Meeting Request while the one with vCalendar appears as an attachment. When I double click the attachment, it opens up as an Appointment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out myself.

iCalendar is used to display Meeting Requests while vCalendar is used for Appointments. Meeting Requests have attendees while Appointments don't.

Comment: This is wrong though :) Your first suggestion is correct. vCal (as a spec) is the 1.0 version, and this was succeeded by the iCalendar (2.0) spec in 1998.